# SeleniumHQ htmlSuite Run Plugin not clicking

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have a jenkins set up on a windows 2012 R2 server.  We have added the plugin SeleniumHQ htmlsuite run plugin.  We can execute the call manually on the server and everything runs fine. When we run it from Jenkins we get this error:

```
2017-07-19 10:41:46.603:INFO::main: Logging initialized @8197ms to     org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
2017-07-19 10:41:46.666:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
2017-07-19 10:41:46.697:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started     o.s.j.s.h.ContextHandler@fbd1f6{/tests,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-07-19 10:41:46.713:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started     ServerConnector@1c0f706{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:39902}
2017-07-19 10:41:46.713:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @8313ms
Jul 19, 2017 10:41:48 AM org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.CoreTestCase run
INFO: |open | http://10.33.2.51/User/AccessSignin/Start |  |
Jul 19, 2017 10:41:51 AM org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.CoreTestCase run
INFO: |type | id=UsernameField | badroutingtesting |
Jul 19, 2017 10:41:51 AM org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.CoreTestCase run
INFO: |clickAndWait | id=SubmitNext |  |
Jul 19, 2017 10:41:52 AM org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.CoreTestCase run
INFO: |click | id=PasswordField |  |
SmallTest.html
<a href="SmallTest.html">SmallTest</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
2017-07-19 10:41:53.057:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Stopped     ServerConnector@1c0f706{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:39902}
2017-07-19 10:41:53.057:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Stopped     o.s.j.s.h.ContextHandler@fbd1f6{/tests,null,UNAVAILABLE}
Jul 19, 2017 10:41:53 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
Jul 19, 2017 10:41:54 AM org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher     mainInt
WARNING: Test of browser failed: *firefox
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: quit
```

It seems to me that it's not executing the click or it's not able to get to the next page.  Same things happens for IE and Chrome.  Could it be a permissions issue? Or is it a configuration with Jenkins?  I'm a bit stumped